# Avoid drawing of hidden components (FLEX)

Tags: performance, apache-flex, render, mxml, hidden

We have big components to draw. Now we have performance problems. We are using visible and includeinlayout properties to hide some components, but they are still rendered by flex.

Is there a possibility to avoid that?!

Is it only possible if we delete the component from the displaylist or can we somehow override the draw method of the component and check if it is hidden or not and depending on that it will be drawn or not.??

Comment: I would say you should try to override the updateDisplayList() method and skip any login in case of "visible" == false;

Comment: Why not delete them from display list? It saves memory.

Comment: did you try my answer?  I use it for the same reason you are complaining about and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever components you don't want drawn yet, put in any SkinnableContainer based container with creationPolicy="none" (don't create my children for me automatically).  Then later on ... if and when you want flex to create those components, you can do this:

```
// here frame is my container with creationPolicy="none" set on it
public function update():void{
if(frame && !frame.deferredContentCreated){
    frame.createDeferredContent();
}
}
```